# Naming a table in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to use Python to set the name of a table to the current datetime.  However, I keep getting a syntax error.  I have tried a couple different things which you'll see below.  Please help if you can.  Thanks!

Option One:

```
import sqlite3, datetime
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%d%m')(col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT)")
```

Option Two:

```
import sqlite3, datetime
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()
varOne = datetime.datetime.now(strftime('%Y%d%m')
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE {tn} (col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT)".format(tn = varOne))
```

Both of these give the same Operational Error near [some character]: syntax error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Save `"CREATE TABLE {tn} (col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT)".format(tn = varOne)` in a separate variable and try!

Answer (score 1):

try following solution. it's working for me.

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
now = datetime.now()
table_name = '[' + datetime.strftime(now,'%Y%d%m') + ']'
sql = "create table %s (%s text,%s text)" % (table_name,"col1","col2")
c.execute(sql)
```